# Obtaining a field from another model using a virtual field

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

There are 2 models defined in Sequelize: User and Department (the relationship between the two models is one-to-many with idDepartment defined in the User model).

In the User model the department name should be obtained in a virtual field called "departmentName".

User.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        validate: {
          isUUID: 4,
        },
      },
  
      departmentName: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
        get() {
          // get "name" field from Department model
        },
      },
    });
};
```

Department.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define(
    "Department",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        validate: {
          isUUID: 4,
        },
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true,
        },
      },
   });
};
```

index.js:

```
Department.hasMany(User, {
  foreignKey: {
    name: "idDepartment",
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      isUUID: 4,
    },
  },
});
User.belongsTo(Department, {
  foreignKey: "idDepartment",
});
```

Comment: Why not use [eager loading](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#eager-loading-example)? Get the user and department in one query.